# kotlin Flow, how to use the override collect function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

Learning the FLow, saw a code returns Flow.
But dont understand how the passed in "block" is called by calling the

```
flow.collect { value ->
    println(value)
}
```

the related code;

```
internal inline fun <T> unsafeFlow(crossinline block: suspend FlowCollector<T>.() -> Unit): Flow<T> {
    return object : Flow<T> {
        override suspend fun collect(collector: FlowCollector<T>) {
            collector.block()
        }
    }
}

suspend fun FlowCollector<Int>.loopFunc() {
    for (i in 1..5) {
        emit(i)
    }
}

val flow: Flow<Int> = unsafeFlow<Int> {
    loopFunc()
}

flow.collect { value ->
    println(value)
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not clear to you? `collect()` is the way how we consume flow items. Flow calls our callback with subsequent items. This is similar to `forEach {}` for collections, but it works asynchronously.

Comment: my question is how the override suspend fun collect(collector: FlowCollector<T>) is called when making the flow.collect { value ->
    println(value)
}

Comment: Well, `flow.collect` **is** your overridden `collect` function, isn't? I mean... it is called, because you call it. Sorry, I have problems seeing your point :-)

Comment: This is no different from any other object where you're overriding a function, and then calling the function on that object.

Comment: I am learning the Flow. I see the sample has the override suspend fun collect(collector: FlowCollector<T>) {
            collector.block()
        } with signature collect(collector: FlowCollector<T>). 
But the 
flow.collect { value ->
    println(value)
} seems not call on that override fun collect(collector: FlowCollector<T>)

Comment: It is calling that function. Maybe your confusion comes not from flows, but from [trailing lambda syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas), from [SAM conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html) or lambdas in general?

Comment: `flow.collect { value -> println(value) }` basically means we create an implementation of `FlowCollector` with the above code, then we invoke `flow.collect()` passing this collector as an argument.

Comment: Passing trailing lambdas: "if the last parameter of a function is a function, then a lambda expression passed as the corresponding argument can be placed outside the parentheses". With "basically means we create an implementation of FlowCollector with the above code, then we invoke flow.collect() passing this collector as an argument", so  the flow.collect { value -> println(value) } has the implementation of FlowCollector passed in. Then which one is the `collector.block()` in this `FlowCollector` implemented?  Still trying to connect dots and thx you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: after discussing this in comments, apparently the confusion came mostly from [trailing lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas) and [SAM conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html). Author also asked how this code actually works.

Let's start with basics:

- `FlowCollector` - consumer of items from a flow. It is a passive side, items are emitted (pushed) into it.
- `Flow` - source of items. They can be consumed by providing a collector to it. Then the flow emits into our collector.
- `loopFunc()` - we can call it a generator function. It receives a collector and produces items by emitting them into that collector. It is somehow similar to a flow, because it accepts a collector and emits to it. But it is not a standard way to represent a source of items - usually, we use a flow.
- `unsafeFlow()` - it converts this generator function into a flow. It creates a flow and if we collect from it (provide a collector to it), the only thing it does is delegating to a stored generator function.

Now, explaining this code:

```kotlin
flow.collect { value ->
    println(value)
}
```

It uses trailing lambda syntax and SAM conversion. It is the same as:

```kotlin
flow.collect(object : FlowCollector<Int> {
    override suspend fun emit(value: Int) {
        println(value)
    }
})
```

Summing everything up, the code flow is like this:

1. We create a flow by using `unsafeFlow()`. This flow stores `loopFunc()` generator function and simply delegates to it when collected.
2. We create a collector which simply prints items emitted into it.
3. We collect from the flow by providing the collector to it.
4. Flow created in `unsafeFlow()` simply passes the collector to `loopFunc()`.
5. `loopFunc()` runs a loop, calling our collector with subsequent items.
6. When the loop ends, we return from `loopFunc()` and then from the `flow.collect()` function, so the code can continue.

The whole code could be really simplified to this:

```kotlin
FlowCollector<Int> { value -> println(value) }.loopFunc()
```

But it uses a `Flow` in the middle which adds complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explain. But not sure if this is accurate:
`It uses trailing lambda syntax and SAM conversion.`
The 
`flow.collect(object : FlowCollector<Int> {
    override suspend fun emit(value: Int) {
        println(value)
    }
}) ` I believe is using interface definition the `public interface Flow<out T> {public suspend fun collect(collector: FlowCollector<T>)}`

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you again. When we call `Flow.collect(FlowCollector)` function passing a lambda, this lambda is converted into an implementation of `FlowCollector` (SAM conversion). This is exactly what the code above does - it creates an anonymous implementation of `FlowCollector` and passes it to `flow.collect()`. If you copy my above code into IntelliJ, it will even suggest you replacing it with the lambda and then you will get your original code back. Because they're both the same code.

Answer (score 0):

ok, try to see if this understanding is correct.

in [kotlinx.coroutines.flow](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/5b64a1fcf36cbea6fbe3cf70966f4907a2a5f92f/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/terminal/Collect.kt#L50), it has an extension function which takes a parameter of a function.

```
@Deprecated(level = DeprecationLevel.HIDDEN, message = "Backwards compatibility with JS and K/N")
public suspend inline fun <T> Flow<T>.collect(crossinline action: suspend (value: T) -> Unit): Unit =
    collect(object : FlowCollector<T> {
        override suspend fun emit(value: T) = action(value)
    })
```

So the

```
flow.collect { value ->
    println(value)
}
```

is calling into it with lambda as the param.
In the extension function, it calls the `collect` function on the Flow instance (which the return from the unsafeFlow()) with a FlowCollector object which has override `override suspend fun emit(value: T) = action(value)`:

```
collect(object : FlowCollector<T> {
        override suspend fun emit(value: T) = action(value)
    })
```

In the unsafeFlow():

```
internal inline fun <T> unsafeFlow(crossinline block: suspend FlowCollector<T>.() -> Unit): Flow<T> {
    return object : Flow<T> {
        override suspend fun collect(collector: FlowCollector<T>) {
            collector.block()
        }
    }
}
```

It passed in a `crossinline block: suspend FlowCollector<T>.() -> Unit`, and the lambda expression `block` in the `unsafeFlow` function signature is callable as if it were a member function of FlowCollector. This is made possible by the concept of function literals with receiver in Kotlin (Function literals with receiver in Kotlin allow you to define functions that are called as if they were member functions of a specific receiver type).

So

So when the `collect(collector: FlowCollector<T>)` of the Flow returned from `unsafeFlow()` is called, in it the `block()` is called which calls the override emit(value: T) of the FlowCollector, which is the `println(value)`.

Hope this is what happened for the code snippet.

**Update:**
@broot is right and thanks!. The `fun interface FlowCollector<in T>`  is a function (SAM) interface, so the

```
flow.collect { value ->
    println(value)
}
```

it converts the lambda expression into the interface implementation, it is same as:

```
flow.collect(object : FlowCollector<Int> {
    override suspend fun emit(value: Int) {
        println(value)
    }
})
```

Comment: This deprecated function from the first snippet is not used here. We call the `collect(FlowCollector)` directly by passing a lambda (again, read about SAM conversions). Other than that I think you got it right, although to be honest, I have problems understanding some parts of the answer.